# Remote Desktop leaves host unresponsive

Tags: remote-desktop

I have my desktop PC at home set up to accept remote connections, and I often connect to it from work on my laptop via mstsc.exe. However, every time I remote to it, I find when I go home that despite the monitor being on - it's not receiving an image and it looks as though the computer is hibernating/asleep. I basically have to restart it whenever I get home and I know there's an answer for why its doing this.

More details:

- When exiting the remote session, I have tried both logging off the account, and closing the RDP window without logging off; both give the same result.
- When I get home to the desktop I of course try moving the mouse, ctrl+alt+del to see if its responsive to restart, multiple key-press to see if I can get any audio out of it; It seems pretty obvious its sleeping/hibernating in some way: Nothing happens in any of these cases and a physical restart is necessary.
- Both desktop and laptop are running Windows 7 Ultimate.

I'm thinking it really is sleeping/hibernating it, and I'm not sure why because left alone my desktop's power options are set to never turn off the HDD or change its state - I leave it on 24/7.

This could be a stupid error on my part but I just can't see it! Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a typical lock-PC-on-RDP-connect but isn't unlocking after you disconnect.  check [this related question](http://superuser.com/questions/80334/remote-desktop-connection-without-locking-the-remote-computer) or some of the other "related" questions in the sidebar to see if one describes your issue.

Comment: As an alternative, you might try using LogMeIn or GoToMyPC.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link to that other question @quack quixote, the first answer lead me to this [post](http://forum.soft32.com/windows/stop-Remote-Desktop-locking-host-ftopict360189.html) - where the answer goes as follows:

> ...The following command can be run on the 
>   remote computer and it will leave the system unlocked with the 
>   account that was used during the remote session logged on.
>
> **tscon.exe 0 /dest:console**
>
> I connect remotely to my XP Pro system using the credentials of 
>   the main account on that machine. I created a batch file that 
>   runs that command and placed it in the C:\Windows folder of the 
>   remote computer. The batch file is named Disconnect.bat. I then 
>   put a shortcut to the batch file in the All Users\Desktop 
>   folder. I also changed the shortcut's icon to match the one for 
>   "Turn Off Computer" on the Start menu.
>
> Instead of closing the remote desktop connection on my local 
>   computer, I double click the shortcut on the remote computer to 
>   end the session.

Works great!

Edit: As per the question quack linked: If you get the error: "Could not connect sessionID 0 to sessionname console, Error code 5 Error [5]:Access is denied." - Your sessionID may be another number. In the comments @yossis suggests a script as follows to remedy this:

> I managed to make it work by trying different session numbers. The session number is different every time I use remote desktop. So I wrote a small script to try out 10 session numbers: for %%i in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do ( tscon %%i /dest:console ) It should be executed as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

tscon.exe 0 /dest:console

I run this command first it was great. Then after few hrs like 15-18 hrs it turn my 3ghz pc to 200mhz pc. It slow down my pc so much that it was difficult to any thing. there is some serious problem in  it which should be fixed.